# Does Google App Engine support session_affinity in the java flexible environment?

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, app.yaml

I have enabled the

```
network:
  session_affinity: true
```

in my app.yaml but it doesn't work neither it's shown enabled when viewing the configuration by going to App Engine > Versions > Config > View.

Here is what I get there:

```
runtime: java

api_version: '1.0'

env: flexible

threadsafe: true

handlers:

  - url: /.*

    script: 'this field is required, but ignored'

automatic_scaling:

  min_num_instances: 2

  max_num_instances: 20

  cpu_utilization:

    target_utilization: 0.5

network: {}

resources:

  cpu: 1

  memory_gb: 4

  disk_size_gb: 10
```

I'm using Spring Boot 2.1 btw.

Answer (score 1):

Session affinity is a Beta feature. In order to use this feature you need to deploy with the beta command.

```
gcloud beta app deploy
```

After the deployment completes, you should see the below line in your config view.

network:
  session_affinity: true

Answer (score 0):

This is not a beta feature anymore, it's now available in mainstream gcloud but bugged, as explained here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154647126

For some reason, deploying does not display the parameter as set (in App Engine > Versions > Display config for a version) and it's not working for some people, I can confirm as I'm affected by the issue myself.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is fixed in gcloud *v356.0.0*

Run `gcloud components update` to upgrade to the latest version.

Reference: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154647126?pli=1